# How do I fix my message encryption/decryption program?

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm making a program that takes user input and either encrypts it or decrypts it using my custom dictionary.

The encryption works just fine, but I'm having issues making the decryption process work. For example, when you encrypt the letter "a", the letter becomes the number "22". but if you try to decrypt the number "22", it outputs "hh" since my dictionary has the letter "h" set to "2" and "a" set to "22".

How do I fix this? I'm a high school student with not a lot of experience with Python and would love any feedback regarding my program.

```
#The dictionary i used for the translation is as follows: T=1 H=2 E=3 Q=4 U=5 I=6 C=7 K=8 B=9 R=10 O=11 W=12 N=13 F=14 X=15 J=16 M=17 P=18 S=19 V=20 L=21 A=22 Z=23 Y=24 D=25 G=26

#Encryption Function
def encrypt(text):
  code = {' ': ' ', 'a': '22 ', 'b': '9 ', 'c': '7 ', 'd': '25 ', 'e': '3 ', 'f': '14 ', 'g': '26 ', 'h': '2 ', 'i': '6 ', 'j': '16 ', 'k': '8 ', 'l': '21 ', 'm': '17 ', 'n': '13 ', 'o': '11 ', 'p': '18 ', 'q': '4 ', 'r': '10 ', 's': '19 ', 't': '1 ', 'u': '5 ', 'v': '20 ', 'w': '12 ', 'x': '15 ', 'y': '24 ', 'z': '23 '}
  
  encryption = ""

  for x in text:
   encryption += code[x.lower()]

  return encryption

#Decryption Function
def decrypt(number):
  code = {' ': ' ', '22': 'a', '9': 'b', '7': 'c', '25': 'd', '3': 'e', '14': 'f', '26': 'g', '2': 'h', '6': 'i', '16': 'j', '8': 'k', '21': 'l', '17': 'm', '13': 'n', '11': 'o', '18': 'p', '4': 'q', '10': 'r', '19': 's', '1': 't', '5': 'u', '20': 'v', '12': 'w', '15': 'x', '24': 'y', '23': 'z'}
  decryption = ""

  for y in number:
   decryption += code[y]

  return decryption
#Variable to loop user input if input isn't valid
Loop = 1

while Loop == 1:
 #user input 
 Option = str.lower(input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a message?: "))
 #encryption
 if Option == "encrypt":
  Encryption_Text = input("What is the message you would like to encrypt: ")
  print(encrypt(Encryption_Text))
  Loop = 0
 #decryption
 elif Option == "decrypt":
  Decryption_Number = input("What is the message you would like to decrypt: ")
  print(decrypt(Decryption_Number))
  Loop = 0
 #invalid user input
 else:
  print("please input a valid option...")
  Loop = 1
```

Comment: Once you have the program in a state where it is working as intended, you can ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get additional suggestions for how to improve it generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a breakpoint before `for y in number:`, then debug, continue, you will find number 22 is spilted, like the following pic shows:

[image]

From VARIABLES in the left block, you can see `y:2`, so you'll get `h` and output is `hh`

In this project you can change `decryption += code[y]` into `decryption = code[number]`

**[edit]**

since you want to input more than one number, you can accept the numbers and using `split()`,

code changes are below:

```
for y in number.split():
        
        decryption += code[y]+" "
```

Comment: I've made the change you have mentioned and it works if I only input one number. So if I input "24", it outputs "y". The only problem is that if I try to input more than one number, like "24 23", rather than outputting "y z", it gives me a key error. I'm also really curious about the text editor you're using. I'm currently using one that runs in my browser and would like to switch over to the one you're using. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: this is visual studio code and i installed python extension, you can download from [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/), and [references](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you for the help and for telling me about visual studio. I've been using it and it works great. Do you have any recommendations or advice on how I can debug my code if any issues arise?

Comment: You're welcome, About Debug you can reference: [python_debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this

```
    # The dictionary i used for the translation is as follows: T=1 H=2 E=3 Q=4 U=5 I=6 C=7 K=8 B=9 R=10 O=11 W=12 N=13 F=14 X=15 J=16 M=17 P=18 S=19 V=20 L=21 A=22 Z=23 Y=24 D=25 G=26

# Encryption Function
def encrypt(text):
    code = {' ': '-', 'a': '22 ', 'b': '9 ', 'c': '7 ', 'd': '25 ', 'e': '3 ', 'f': '14 ', 'g': '26 ', 'h': '2 ',
            'i': '6 ', 'j': '16 ', 'k': '8 ', 'l': '21 ', 'm': '17 ', 'n': '13 ', 'o': '11 ', 'p': '18 ', 'q': '4 ',
            'r': '10 ', 's': '19 ', 't': '1 ', 'u': '5 ', 'v': '20 ', 'w': '12 ', 'x': '15 ', 'y': '24 ', 'z': '23 '}

    encryption = ""

    for x in text:
        encryption += code[x.lower()]

    return encryption


# Decryption Function
def decrypt(number):
    code = {" ":" ", '-': ' ', '22': 'a', '9': 'b', '7': 'c', '25': 'd', '3': 'e', '14': 'f', '26': 'g', '2': 'h',
            '6': 'i', '16': 'j', '8': 'k', '21': 'l', '17': 'm', '13': 'n', '11': 'o', '18': 'p', '4': 'q', '10': 'r',
            '19': 's', '1': 't', '5': 'u', '20': 'v', '12': 'w', '15': 'x', '24': 'y', '23': 'z'}
    decryption = ""

    numbers = number.split(" ")
    del numbers[-1]
    for y in numbers:
        if "-" in y:
            num = y.split("-")[1]
            decryption += " " + code[num]
        else:
            decryption += code[y]

    return decryption


# Variable to loop user input if input isn't valid
Loop = 1

while Loop == 1:
    # user input
    Option = str.lower(input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a message?: "))
    # encryption
    if Option == "1":
        Encryption_Text = input("What is the message you would like to encrypt: ")
        print(encrypt(Encryption_Text))
        Loop = 0
    # decryption
    elif Option == "2":
        Decryption_Number = input("What is the message you would like to decrypt: ")
        print(decrypt(Decryption_Number))
        Loop = 0
    # invalid user input
    else:
        print("please input a valid option...")
        Loop = 1
```

i have modified the decrypt method, after seeing the comment under the other answer

Comment: I've tried your code and it works the way I wanted it do, but I've realized that when inputting the numbers for the decryption function, you have to put a space after every number in order for the function to output all the characters.I don't understand how you were able to come up with this solution and was wondering if you have any tips for me to implement when debugging code for issues that may arise or how I can learn from the solution you made. Thanks for your feedback.